# subsystem configuration

Tags: probability, reliability, subsystem

What is the minimum number of subsystems that need to be configured in parallel in order to increase the availability of the entire system to 99% or more, if the availability of each subsystem in the parallel system shown below is 70%?

Assume that the entire system is running as long as one subsystem is running.

diagram:

[image: diagram]
http://postimage.org/image/tdv2xfwk/

The answer is 4 but I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a programming question such as a probability question. Assuming that subsystem failures are independent events (this is NOT obvious - the question is flawed for leaving this out, but unsolvable if we don't assume it), we can consider the probability for NOT all subsystems being NOT available.

Since "NOT-available" are independent events, we can compute the probability of "all subsystems being NOT available" by multiplying the probabilities of each individual event, as in `(1-p)^n`, where `p` is the probabilty of a system being available (0.7 in this case), and `n` is the number of subsystems.

Then to get back the probability of at least one being available - that is, NOT all being NOT available, just invert the probability, with `1-(1-p)^n`. Now just find the lowest value of `n` for which this comes out to be at least `0.99`.